# Find h(x) so $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)h(x)dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f(x) > 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, then can I find $h(x)$ on $(0, \infty)$ with $h(x) \not= 0$ such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)h(x)dx$ converges? I think so yes, because $h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+1$ works right?

Comment: Well you gave a specific $f(x)$. Aren't you given an arbitrary $f(x)$, then asked to find $h(x)$?

Comment: How about $h(x) =\frac{1}{x^2f(x)}$? Also, your example doesn't work because $fh = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x}$ diverges.

Comment: JLinsta is correct. The statement applies to any $f > 0$. Demonstrating it works for a single $f$ is not sufficient to prove it. You might want to consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1& x\text{ is rational}\\2&x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$$